# Is it possible to prove that if $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$, then $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{\dagger} \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{b}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

Suppose $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ Is it possible to prove that if there exists $\mathbf{x}$ such that $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$, then $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{\dagger} \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{b}$? I think proving this result would mean using the SVD of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}$ but I get that $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{\dagger} \mathbf{b} = (\mathbf{U} \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{I}_{r \times r} & \mathbf{0}_{r \times q-r} \\ \mathbf{0}_{q-r \times r}   & \mathbf{0}_{q-r \times q-r}\end{bmatrix} \mathbf{U}^*) \mathbf{b} $ where q is minimum of man and r is the rank. I also think it might have to do with null space of A being the last q-r vectors of V and colspace is first r vectors of U.

Comment: I am curious to know does this have an application in least square problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pseudoinverse by definition has the property
$$
A=AA^\dagger A
$$
Multiply from the right by $x$ and use $Ax=b$ to get
$$
Ax=AA^\dagger Ax\\
b=AA^\dagger b
$$

Answer (score 0):

$A^{\dagger}$ is a pseudoinvers of $A$. Hence $AA^{\dagger}$ is idempotent and $ im(AA^{\dagger})=im(A).$

If $Ax=b$, then $b \in im(AA^{\dagger})$ . Since $AA^{\dagger}$ is idempotent , we get $AA^{\dagger}b=b$ .